# Проверка на null Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

В своем проекте React Typescript я использую хук useRef и далее пытаюсь получить свойство current.

`const audioPlayer = useRef<HTMLMediaElement>(null);`

Далее пишу: `audioPlayer.current.currentTime` и TS ругается на на что audioPlayer.current может быть null.

Приходится каждый раз делать проверку `if (audioPlayer.current)`

И таких случаев очень много, что делает код не очень приятным
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это можно как-то упростить?

Comment: `audioPlayer?.current?.currentTime`. Подробнее в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Я использую присваивание поэтому TS ругается, что "Левая часть выражения присваивания не может быть обращением к необязательному свойству."

Comment: Такс, тогда пожалуйста показывайте ваш код полностью (не всмысле прям весь код, а где идёт проверка и присвоение)

Comment: if (audioPlayer.current)  audioPlayer.current.currentTime = +(progressBar.current?.value || 1);

Comment: Такие детали надо вставлять в сам вопрос, чтобы все сразу всё видели

Comment: Впредь буду учитывать

Comment: Можно начать хоть прямо сейчас нажав на кнопку "Править" под вашим вопросом :)

Answer (score -1):

В TypeScript для этого можно использовать оператор `!`

```typescript
const audioPlayer = useRef<HTMLMediaElement>(null);

...

audioPlayer.current!.play()
//                ^^^^
```

Comment: и в данном случае это может вызвать ошибку во время выполнения, когда значение действительно `null`

Comment: @Grundy, вопрос прочитай

> Приходится каждый раз делать проверку if (audioPlayer.current)

Comment: Потому что поле действительно может быть `null`, как только ты убираешь проверку, есть вероятность, что попробуешь обратиться к полю, когда его значение `null` - и вполне себе упадешь